# Error in Query method of a Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to use a Content Provider but I have the error:

The method query(Uri, String[], String, String[], String) in the type MCProvider is not applicable for the arguments (Uri, String[], String[], String[], String[])

My code:

```
public class MapaLugares extends FragmentActivity {

   SQLiteDatabase db;
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa_lugares);
    final MCProvider Provc = new MCProvider();
    final String AUT = "com.app.mapa.MCProvider";
    final Uri C_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUT+Bdoh.T_NOMBRE);
    final String[] p = new String[] {com.app.mapa.MCProvider.latitud, 
            com.app.mapa.MCProvider.longitud};
    Cursor crs;

    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
            Point coord = proj.toScreenLocation(point);
            final String[] s = new String[] 
                          {com.app.mapa.MCProvider.latitud + " = '" + point.latitude + 
            "AND" + com.app.mapa.MCProvider.longitud + " = '" +   
                             point.longitude};
            final String[] sarg=null;
            final String[] sorder=null;

                            Provc.query(C_URI, p, s, sarg, sorder);

                    }

    });
}
```

The Content Provider:

```
    public class MCProvider extends ContentProvider {

private static final String AUTH = "com.app.mapa.MCProvider";
private static final Uri CP_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+AUTH+Bdoh.T_NOMBRE);
private static int COMMENT = 1;
public static String latitud;
public static String longitud;

SQLiteDatabase bd;
Bdoh bdHelper;

    private static final UriMatcher Umatcher;

static
{
    Umatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    Umatcher.addURI(AUTH, Bdoh.T_NOMBRE, COMMENT);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() 
{

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bdHelper = new Bdoh(getContext());

    return true;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues cvalues) 
{

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bd = bdHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    if(Umatcher.match(uri)==COMMENT)
    {
        bd.insert(Bdoh.T_NOMBRE, null, cvalues);
    }

    bd.close();

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

    return null;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] 
    selectionargs, String sortorder) 
 {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cursor cr;

    bd = bdHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    //bd.query
    cr = bd.query(Bdoh.T_NOMBRE, projection, selection, selectionargs, null, 
            null, sortorder);
    cr.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);


    return cr;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri arg0, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

The SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
    public class Bdoh extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
String bdcons = "CREATE TABLE lugares (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    nombre TEXT, descripcion TEXT, latitud DOUBLE, longitud DOUBLE, foto TEXT)";
SQLiteOpenHelper sbd;
static String T_NOMBRE="lugares"; //para el content provider

Cursor cr;
String TBD="lugares"; //tabla de la base de datos

public Bdoh(Context context) 
{
    super(context, "lugares", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase 

            db=context.openOrCreateDatabase("lugares",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null); 
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(bdcons);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lugares");

    db.execSQL(bdcons);
}

public void insertar(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{

      db=sbd.getWritableDatabase();


      cr=db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO lugares ", null);
}

}
```

Why is this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error fixed. The problem was in the onMapClick event in the MapaLugares class where the declarations of Strings are without [] except sarg variable.